# HTML Canvas & JavaScript - Redefining Object on Selection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

The script below draws an image on the left side of the screen and a selection box in the right. It then attempts to redefine the image drawn on the left on each new selection in the selection box on the right by making the `imageID` dependent on the selection. However, as you can see below, whatever number you select on the right the image remains the same (`1`) because whilst it might be redrawn, it is not **redefined** on selection. What I would like to happen is that on selection in the box on the right the number in the image changes with the selection box such that it always correlates with the selection. In other words, when you click on 2 the image changes to the 2nd image in `images`. I have found two ways of doing this but they are both flawed:

**1:** Define `img` in `paint`'s `render` function. This works but it makes everything run very slowly and the hover animations on the image stop working as expected.

**2:** Define `img` in the `makeSelectionInfo` function. This also works but the hover animations completely stop working if this is done.

I apologise for the long code but I couldn't condense it any more. For the sake of brevity I have only included images for numbers between 1 & 5. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
  canvasX=c.offsetLeft,
  canvasY=c.offsetTop,
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');

images=['https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfN4z.jpg',
        'https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyQS1.png',
        'https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vlfj.jpg',
        'https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3NLH.jpg',
        'https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnLwl.png'];

var curvedRect = function(text, x, y, w, h) {
this.text = text;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.w = w;
this.h = h;
this.hovered = false;
this.clicked = false;
}

curvedRect.prototype.makeCurvedRect = function() {
var delta=0, theta=0, yRotation=this.y;
if (this.hovered) {
 delta = 3;
 shadowColor = '#000000';
 shadowBlur = 20;
 shadowOffsetX = 5;
 shadowOffsetY = 5;
 theta = -0.01;
} else {
 delta = 0;
 theta = 0;
 shadowColor = '#9F3A9B';
 shadowBlur = 0;
 shadowOffsetX = 0;
 shadowOffsetY = 0;
}
var x = this.x-delta;
var y = yRotation-delta;
var w = this.w+(2*delta);
var h = this.h+(2*delta);
var img=new Image();
img.src=images[this.text];
ctx.rotate(theta);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth='8';
ctx.strokeStyle='white';
ctx.moveTo(x+10, y);
ctx.lineTo(x+w-10, y);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+10);
ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-10);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y+h, x+w-10, y+h);
ctx.lineTo(x+10, y+h);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h-10);
ctx.lineTo(x, y+10);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+10, y);
ctx.shadowColor = shadowColor;
ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
ctx.drawImage(img, x+2.5, y+2.5, w-5, h-5);
ctx.rotate(-theta);
}

curvedRect.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
return (x >= this.x) && (x <= (this.w+this.x)) && (y >= this.y) && (y <= (this.h+this.y));
}

var selectionForMenu = function(id, text, y) {
 this.id = id;
 this.text = text;
 this.y = y;
 this.hovered = false;
 this.clicked = false;
 this.lastClicked = false;
}
function makeTextForSelected(text, y) {
    ctx.font='bold 12px Noto Sans';
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.fillText(text, 200, y);
}

function makeSelectionInfo(text) {
    makeTextForSelected(text, 375);
}

selectionForMenu.prototype.makeSelection = function() {
 var fillColor='#A84FA5';
 if (this.hovered) {
  if (this.clicked) {
   if (this.lastClicked) {
    fillColor='#E4C7E2';
   } else {
    fillColor='#D5A9D3';
   }
  } else if (this.lastClicked) {
   fillColor='#D3A4D0';
   makeSelectionInfo(this.text);
  } else {
   fillColor='#BA74B7';
  }
 } else if (this.lastClicked) {
  fillColor='#C78DC5';
  makeSelectionInfo(this.text);
 } else {
  fillColor='#A84FA5';
 }
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle=fillColor;
 ctx.fillRect(400, this.y, 350, 30)
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.font='10px Noto Sans';
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.textAlign='left';
 ctx.fillText(this.text, 410, this.y+19);
}

selectionForMenu.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (x >= 400) && (x <= (750)) && (y >= this.y) && (y <= (this.y+30)) && !((x >= 400) && (y > 450));
}

var Paint = function(element) {
 this.element = element;
 this.shapes = [];
}

Paint.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
 this.shapes.push(shape);
}

Paint.prototype.render = function() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.element.width, this.element.height);

 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  try {
   this.shapes[i].makeSelection();
  }
  catch(err) {}
  try {
   this.shapes[i].makeCurvedRect();
  }
  catch(err) {}
 }

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 750, 25);
 ctx.stroke();

 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  try {
   this.shapes[i].makeBox();
  }
  catch(err) {}
 }

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle='#BC77BA';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 450, 750, 50);
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.font='bold 10px Noto Sans';
 ctx.fillStyle='#9F3A9B';
 ctx.textAlign='center';
 ctx.fillText('Phrase Practice', 365, 17);

 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  try {
   this.shapes[i].makeInteractiveButton();
  }
  catch(err) {}
 }
}

Paint.prototype.setHovered = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].hovered = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.setClicked = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].clicked = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.setUnclicked = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  if (shape.constructor.name==this.shapes[i].constructor.name) {
   this.shapes[i].clicked = false;
    if (shape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
    this.shapes[i].lastClicked = this.shapes[i] == shape;
   }
  }
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.select = function(x, y) {
 for (var i=this.shapes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (this.shapes[i].hitTest(x, y)) {
   return this.shapes[i];
  }
 }
 return null
}

imageID = 0;

var paint = new Paint(c);
var img = new curvedRect(imageID, 112.5, 100, 175, 175);
var selection = [];
for (i=0; i<=30; i++) {
 selection.push(new selectionForMenu(i, i, 25+(i*30)));
}

paint.addShape(img);
for (i=0; i<30; i++) {
 paint.addShape(selection[i])
}

paint.render();

var clickedShape=0;
var i=0;
function mouseDown(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);
 if (shape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
  imageTextID = shape.id;
  if (i==0) {
   clickedShape=shape;
   i=1;
  } else if (i==1) {
   i=0;
  }
 }
 paint.setClicked(shape);
}

function mouseUp(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);
 if (clickedShape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
  if (x>400 && y>25 && y<450) {
   paint.setUnclicked(shape);
  } else if (shape && !(shape instanceof selectionForMenu)) {
   paint.setUnclicked(shape);
  }
 }
}

function mouseMove(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);

 paint.setHovered(shape);
}

c.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

```css
canvas {
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  background: #9F3A9B;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game" width = "750" height = "500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a bunch of code, indeed. The best way would be to load all your assets and save them in an Array. Then once you need to draw one of these, just pick the correct  `<img>` tag your Array will contain.

Comment: Ps: an overly simplified example of what I mean : https://jsfiddle.net/j4eeeoh6/

Comment: Your code seems to have the same problem as mine.. The arrow keys don't work. Also, I think the problem lies in the object `new curvedRect` declaration so the prototype structure is necessary to solve it.

Comment: I didn't really search the error on your code. One obvious is that you don't waot for your image has loaded before drawing it, but it i deed osn't the only one. For my fiddle to work, you need to have the focus on the rendering frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your code here https://jsfiddle.net/0wq0hked/2/

You can diff to see what I changed, but basically you weren't initializing and adding the multiple `curvedRect` to the `Paint.shapes` array. I also added the images as an attribute of `curvedRect`.

I also had to add a `visible` parameter to your shapes, as your mouse hover `Paint.select` function was not functioning properly. The way yours works, shapes that share the same (x,y) do not allow other shapes from being hovered even when they are not visible. Thus multiple shapes occupying the image area to the left stopped the hover from working properly. I suppose you could keep your `Paint.select` and instance/remove shapes when they are to be drawn, but you do not have shape removal functionality as far as I can tell.

Also, you call render on every event, this is a bad idea. Take a look at `requestAnimationFrame` and try drawing at the screen refresh rate rather than on user input.

Comment: I don't know if you're still active but I'm stuck on a related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062247/html-canvas-javascript-selection-menu-setting-initial-and-sustaining-curre